# How to filter till index level in cluster health API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using [Elasticsearch cluster health API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html) and was able to reach to index level in JSON response, like below using endpoint `http://my-es-server:9200/_cluster/health/bar?level=indices&h=indices`

```
  "cluster_name": "foo",
  "status": "green",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 9,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 6,
  "active_primary_shards": 4,
  "active_shards": 12,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "indices": {
    "bar": {
      "status": "green",
      "number_of_shards": 4,
      "number_of_replicas": 2,
      "active_primary_shards": 4,
      "active_shards": 12,
      "relocating_shards": 0,
      "initializing_shards": 0,
      "unassigned_shards": 0
    }
  }
}
```

But all I am interested in just the status field of my indices, not the cluster `status` field and for that I need some response filtering in elasticsearch, I tried h=index or h=status but no luck, these h= works in so many other API but not in health API and I really don't want to parse the JSON, filter my index and get its health status.

It would be great of I can just get the health status of my index ie `green`, `yellow` or `red`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [_cat/indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html), which also returns the health status of the index and also supports filtering based on some param, in this API, index-health is denoted by `health` param instead of `status` in your previous cluster API.

```
http://your-es-server:9200/_cat/indices/bar?h=health
```

Which returns `green`, `yellow`, and `red`.